# The continuity of linear functionals with respect to uniform convergence of entire functions on balls

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, uniform-convergence, banach-algebras, analyticity

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $H_b (X)$ be the algebra of complex-valued entire functions on $X$ which are bounded on bounded sets, with the topology of uniform convergence on bounded sets.

Let $\varphi \in H_b^* (X)$ (which is the dual space of $H_b (X)$).

**Each $\varphi \in H_b^* (X)$ is continuous with respect to the norm of uniform convergence on some ball in $X$.**

Define the *radius function* $R$ on $H_b^* (X)$ by declaring $R(\varphi) $ to be the infimum of all $r >0$ such that $\varphi$ is continuous with respect to the norm of uniform convergence on the ball $r B$.

I don't understand the above bold statement. I am a bit confused because I think $\varphi \in H_b^* (X)$ is continuous on *every* ball in $X$ (so, the radius of $\varphi$ is always $0$).

I want to know what I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, consider $X=\mathbb{C}$. The map $\varphi(f) = f(1)$ is a continuous linear functional on $H_b(\mathbb{C})$.

Consider the sequence $f_n(z)=z^n$ of elements of $H_b(\mathbb{C})$.  On the disk $\frac12B = \{z:|z|<1/2\}$ this sequence converges uniformly to $0$. However, $\varphi(f_n)=1$ does not converge to $0$. So, $\varphi$ is not continuous with respect to the uniform convergence on $\frac12B$.

Based on the above, one can see that $R(\varphi)=1$: uniform convergence on the unit disk is sufficient for convergence of the values of $\varphi$, while uniform convergence on smaller disks is not.

Comment: Thank you very much! It would be crystal clear if I understand the meaning 'the map $\phi$ is a continuous linear functional on $H_b(\mathbb{C})$.' Can you clarify this statement for me?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what I missed is about the exact definition of the given topology on $H_b (\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: A sequence if functions converges in $H_b$ iff for every bounded set, it uniformly converges on that set. This is enough to describe the topology (it's metrizable, so sequences are enough). A functional is continuous if for every convergent sequence of functions, its values converge to what you expect.

Comment: Can you give me a hint to prove that each $\varphi \in H_b^* (X)$ is continuous with respect to the norm of uniform convergence on some ball in $X$?